# Meaning of "in-house" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> And populists the world over have learnt quickly that vilifying the
>   mainstream media is an effective way of closing ranks - especially
>   when combined with the creation of alternative information
>   infrastructures, such as "**in-house**" YouTube and Facebook channels.
>   (The Philosophers' Magazine 14th Quarter 2018, No. 83)

Does "in-house" mean YouTube videos that people produce in their own houses? Or ones that are produces by organizations? In the above sentence, is it an adjective only for "YouTube" or for "Facebook channels" too? In particular, I have problem understanding what the sentence wants to say. Does it say that, by producing YouTube videos and Facebook channels in an organized way for their purposes, they can vilify the media and thus close ranks?

Comment: "In-house", in US business jargon, means some product or service that is provided by a group or division within the company, vs being obtained from an outside "vendor".  In the above it suggests, somewhat differently yet analogously, that these "channels" are developed within the "populist" organization.

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in house**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/house?q=in%20house)
​

> a WORKPLACE: used to describe work that is done by a company's paid
>   employees:

As in:

> we will keep the work in house, and get it done more cost-effectively
>   than by using a contractor.

For your question, the 'productions' are all made by the company/organization (its employees).  They are not let out to outside sources. As such they can be expected to 'tow' the party line.

Comment: Except in the line quoted by the OP there doesn't appear to be a "company" as such, but rather it's a "closing ranks" of a political faction.

Comment: @HotLicks So they make content inside of their organization and release it to change people's mind?? That is what is said here?

Comment: @Sasan - That's how I'd interpret it.   It's unclear whether the "organization" is formal or just a loose group of internet buddies.